# Delete all zeroes at the beginning of files names

Tags: string, powershell

I have some documents in a file starting with different numbers of zeroes. I would like to delete all of these zeroes at the beginning of files.

For example

From

```
010 document.docx
0002  document.docx
030  document.docx
```

to

```
10 document.docx
2  document.docx
30  document.docx
```

I know I can delete these zeroes one by one using the following command.

```
Get-ChildItem *.docx | Rename-Item -NewName { [string]($_.Name).Substring(1) }
```

But can I do this by **one** command?

Comment: take a look at this `'0004'.TrimStart('0')` ... the output is `4`. the `.Trim()` string method and its variants can be quite handy! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to

- replace multiple spaces with one and
- pad left with zeroes to a unique length

---

```
Get-ChildItem [0-9]*.docx|
  Rename-Item -NewName {[regex]::Replace(($_.Name -replace ' +',' '),
                        '^\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(4,'0')})}
```

---

```
>gci *.docx

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-01-04     21:40              2 0002 document.docx
-a----       2019-01-04     21:40              2 0010 document.docx
-a----       2019-01-04     21:40              2 0030 document.docx
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a regular expression to remove leading zeroes from the file names.

```
Get-ChildItem *.docx | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^0+' }
```

`^` matches the beginning of a string (in this case the file name). `0+` matches one or more consecutive zeroes.